# php Error in sql syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' ' at line 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

I am trying to validate an email and password which is entered by a user in to an app that I am making.  To validate the email and password I am using php.  Currently I am getting the error message:

```
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' ' at line 1"
```

Here is my php code in json-config.php:

```
<?php

$host = "localhost"; //Your database host server
$db = "dbname"; //Your database name
$user = "user"; //Your database user
$pass = "pass"; //Your password

$connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);  

if(!$connection) {

die("Database server connection failed.");  

} else {
//Attempt to select the database

$dbconnect = mysql_select_db($db, $connection);
//echo "connection working";
//Check to see if we could select the database

if(!$dbconnect) {
    die("Unable to connect to the specified database!");        
}
}

?>
```

Here is my php code in json.php:

```
<?php
include("json-config.php");

$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

function validate_password($plain, $encrypted) {
    if (!empty($plain) && !empty($encrypted)) {
        // split apart the hash / salt
        $stack = explode(':', $encrypted);
        //echo "<pre>";print_r($stack);echo "</pre>";
        if (sizeof($stack) != 2)
            return false;
        if (md5($stack[1] . $plain) == $stack[0]) {
            return true;
        }
    }

return false;
}

if ($_POST) {
//gets user's info based off of a username.
$query = "SELECT customer_email, customer_password FROM rt_customer WHERE customer_email = ".$email."";
//echo $query;

//This will be the variable to determine whether or not the user's information is correct.
//we initialize it as false.
$validated_info = false;
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Error in Selection Query <br> " . $query . "<br>" . mysql_error());

//fetching all the rows from the query
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    //if we encrypted the password, we would unencrypt it here, but in our case we just
    //compare the two passwords
    if ($this->validate_password($password, $row['customer_password'])) {
        $login_ok = true;
    }
}

// If the user logged in successfully, then we send them to the private members-only page 
// Otherwise, we display a login failed message and show the login form again 
if ($login_ok) {
    echo '{"success":1, "message":"Login successful!"}';
} else {
    echo '{"success":0, "message":"Username and/or password is invalid."}';
}
}

?>
```

If you need any more information please don't hesitate to ask, thank you.

Comment: You're missing quotes around your string value

Comment: Specifically, the unsanitized `$email` that you're passing directly into your query, directly from `$_POST`

Comment: Please, please, please.... stop using the MySQL extension and move to MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements/bind variables

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put quotes around `$email`

```
$query = "SELECT customer_email, customer_password FROM rt_customer ".
         "   WHERE customer_email = '".$email."'";
```

Though this will fix your problem, I'd recommend looking at mysqli and letting prepared statement do the quoting for you.  The way you're using data directly from the post array leaves you open to sql injection.

If you really want to keep the bad-old mysql libraries, use this:

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string( $email);
```

Before you put it in the query (but after you establish your connection).

Comment: or just `"SELECT customer_email, customer_password FROM rt_customer WHERE customer_email = '$email'";`

Comment: @Strawberry yep that would do it too, without the concatenation futz

Comment: When I add the quotes into the query in I receive a connection error from the app. error code: 500.

Comment: @Jaw_khan it shouldn't be the query that's failing, but you can try Strawberry's version it to confirm

Comment: @Ray But I wasn't receiving that error before, could it be something to do with my app code itself?

Comment: @Jaw_khan  if it's a php 500 you may have misstyped.  What is the exact error you see in the error_log? Can you post the full error?

Comment: @Ray The error message is "Query was empty" also error code is now back to 200.

Comment: @Ray sorry my bad the error log is empty for this particular issue

Answer (score 0):

```
1)SELECT customer_email, customer_password FROM rt_customer WHERE customer_email = '$email'"
2)SELECT customer_email, customer_password FROM rt_customer WHERE customer_email = '".$email."'"
```

are correct but follow standard will help you avoid accidental errors,
Always remember to check the condition with a table field of type vachar us single quote ('string value') or double quotes ("string value") around it

Also only back ticks used around(`database name`) or (`table name`) or (`field name`),not use single quote or double quote for these names,
You could use my [blog](http://webdevelopershelp-var23.blogspot.in/2013/06/commen-error-in-sql-query-writting.html) to get more info.